# The "fully grammatical" approach towards learning Indo-European languages

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, grammar

I have stumbled upon this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaMRWoXibME) on Youtube (sorry - it is in Russian).

Here's a short summary:

The spokesperson introduces the following scheme of learning an Indo-European language:

1. "Learn by heart" a book which describes the language's grammar without any exercises, and restrain from approaching any other materials (thus, concentrate on syntax and morphology).
2. Read a book without consulting the dictionary.
3. Read another book consulting the dictionary not more often than thrice a page.

The spokesperson claims that the Indo-European languages follow some patterns which make this approach possible.

Truth be told, I reckon syntactical and morphological to be an imperative part of learning a new language, yet I've never tried concentrating on those points that much.

1. Has anyone tried learning a language following this or some similar scheme?
2. Which patterns could have the spokesperson been hinting at?

---

Edit:

The spokesperson does not specify whether this is exclusively about learning to read the language or also about using it actively. People in the comments referenced a [similar method](http://youtube.com/watch?v=SN-H6DFJ8V8) (the video is once again in Russian, sorry) which is meant for reading according to the author. Others also backed up the "passive" nature of the acquired knowledge and skills.

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE! Interesting question. By "diary", do you mean a dictionary or the book in point 1 of the first numbered list?

Comment: @Tommi Hello! I meant "dictionary" - I've edited the question. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Could you please add what the person in that video means by learning? Is this exclusively about learning to read the language or also about using it actively?

Comment: @Tsundoku frankly speaking, the spokesperson does not specify that. People in the comments referenced a similar method (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SN-H6DFJ8V8 - the video is once again in Russian, sorry) which is meant for reading according to the author. Others also backed up the "passive" nature of the acquired knowledge and skills.